# Binary search on very large data set

Tags: algorithm, search, bigdata, binary-search

How would you go about performing binary search of a very large data set that didn't fit into memory on a single computer?

1. What data store would the data come from? eg. NoSQL?
2. Would this data live in RAM or disk?
3. How would you know how many computers are required?
4. Would there need to be some sort of master computer that got answer from each of the computer nodes?

As a side, any resources you can suggest for learning more about these type of problems are appreciated.

Comment: do you know about hadoop?

Comment: Maybe ordinary databse will suffice? Indexes in databases are structures optimized for performing searches on very large data sets that don't fit into memory.

Comment: Need more information. Is the data set sorted on disk, on a single computer? How fast does the search need to be? Can you load an index (just the keys) in memory and search that, going to the disk only for the final record when found? How about loading a partial index (say, every 16th record) so that you can search the index to narrow it down, then just load 16 records from disk to complete the search? There are many options, but which, if any, is applicable depends on the nature of your data and what your performance target is.

Comment: Why do you think you need *binary* search?  You just need to quickly find one element in many millions or billions of elements, right?  Binary search is one way to do that that is fast for in-memory searches, but as other commenters have said, RDBMSes are highly optimised for this when the data doesn't fit in memory.  Nearly all of them use B-tree or B+tree indices, which are more efficient when using media with slow random access times.